# Handling custom exception message with react-query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

Here is my global exception handler written in `Spring Boot`

```kotlin
data class ErrorResponse(
    val status: Int? = null,
    val message: String? = null
)

@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ItemAlreadyExistsException::class)
    fun handleItemAlreadyExistsException(e: ItemAlreadyExistsException?): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> =
        ResponseEntity(ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), e?.message.toString()), HttpStatus.CONFLICT)

}
```

And here is my `useMutation` function

```js
    const useSignUp = useMutation<Employer, Error, Employer>(
        (employer) => signUpAsEmployer(employer),
        {
            onError: (error) => {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }
    );
```

How can I console log the custom message from thrown Exception?

[image]

`console.log(error.message)` gives me: `"Request failed with status code 409"` while I want the message I marked by arrow on the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    onError: (error as AxiosError) => {
        const response = JSON.parse(error.request.response);
        console.log(response.message);
    }
```

Comment: I get this error:
`TS2339: Property 'request' does not exist on type 'Error'`

Comment: Inform typescript that it's an AxiosError not any ol run of the mill Error. I have edited my answer to add the cast.

Answer (score 0):

The @Chad S. answer works but do not cast the error inside the parenthises like this: `error as AxiosError`
but change the method returned error type from this:

```js
 const useSignUp = useMutation<Employer, Error, Employer>(
        (employer) => signUpAsEmployer(employer),
        {
            onError: (error) => {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }
    );
```

to this:

```js
 const useSignUp = useMutation<Employer, AxiosError, Employer>(
        (employer) => signUpAsEmployer(employer),
        {
            onError: (error) => {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        }
    );
```